# Widget is not full width

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_date_pickers in my app and trying to make it full width.
I followed the example they provide, but it's still not full width. There's some space on both sides

```dart
Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: dp.DayPicker(
            selectedDate: selectedDate,
            onChanged: setNewDate,
            firstDate: now,
            lastDate: now.add(Duration(days: 365)),
            datePickerStyles: dp.DatePickerRangeStyles(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: i haven't tried this package yet but maybe it has some default padding. If that class widget has some padding maybe try to Zero its padding?.

Comment: It is always useful when testing layouts to wrap in a colored widget to see exactly what is happening. I recommend you do this.

Comment: I am not sure if the flex Widget has something to do with this problem. Try replacing it with an Expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by set a **width** for **container** widget:

Use this widget in a **container** with :

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

by this code, you set the width base on the screen.